# How to open multiple dialog from the dialog using WIX

Tags: wix, wix3

I have total 4 dialog, 
1. Installation input screen,
2. Final dialog - This will open when installation is successfully done,
3. Error dialog - This will open when any exception throws while installation,
4. Message dialog.

I have write below code to open respective dialog from the Installation input screen. 
I want to open Message dialog from Error dialog(like alert messaged dialog) when any exception throws while installation. How can I open multiple dialog if any exception throws while installation.

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Show Dialog="ErrorDialog" OnExit="error" />
  <Show Dialog="FinalDialog" OnExit="success" />
</InstallUISequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is actually not necessary. Wix already has a set of dialogs that does almost exactly what you are trying to do. As an example, you can use the [WixUI_Minimal](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_minimal.html) dialog to do what you're trying to do.

In your Product.wxs you would add a UI reference to the WixUI_Minimal dialog set.

```
<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"></UIRef>
</UI>
```

Now you should be good to go. Hope that helps!